# Typescript Generics type fails check

Tags: typescript, generics

```
// RepositoryBase.ts
export type FieldsMapping<T> = { readonly [k in keyof Required<T>]: string };

export abstract class RepositoryBase<T> {
    protected abstract readonly COLUMNS: FieldsMapping<T>;
}

// UsersRepository.ts
import { FieldsMapping, RepositoryBase } from './RepositoryBase';

interface User {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    email?: string;
}

export class UsersRepository extends RepositoryBase<User> {
    protected readonly COLUMNS = {
        firstName: 'first_name',
        lastName: 'last_name',
        email: 'email',
        extra: 'non_existing_column',
    };
}
```

The declaration of `COLUMNS` in `UsersRepository` doesn't give any compiling error, even tho `extra` key doesn't exist on `User` interface.

If I add the type to `COLUMNS` in `UserRepository`, such as: `COLUMNS: FieldsMapping<User>`, then the error is thrown.

I don't want to redeclare the type on each class which inherits `RepositoryBase`. Do you have any idea why this is happening? Is maybe due to the `abstract`? Or maybe is it due to some configuration in `tsconfig.json`? Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you extend an interface or a class with `extends`, you are allowed to make the subinterface/subclass *narrower*, both by adding new properties or by narrowing existing properties.  So it is perfectly acceptable in TypeScript for the `COLUMNS` property of `UserRepository` to be more specific than the `COLUMNS` property of `RepositoryBase<User>`.  That's what `extends` is explicitly intended for.

If you choose to *annotate* the type of the `COLUMNS` property `UserRepository` as `Record<keyof User, string>` (equivalent to your `FieldsMapping<User>`) and use a new object literal in the assignment, you will get [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) and the extra property will be flagged.

If that works for you then you should just do it... it's a bit redundant (you have to write `User` both in the generic parameter of `RepositoryBase<User>` and in the annotation for the `COLUMNS` property), but fairly clean.

Otherwise I don't have any very good fixes for this, mostly because `protected` properties are hard to manipulate programmatically. (e.g., `keyof UserRepository` does not include `COLUMNS`, and thus `UserRepository["COLUMNS"]` is invalid).

I suppose the closest I could get would be a generic method called something like `strictColumns()` that would only accept a field mapping with no known extra properties... the method would just return its input, so you'd use it to initialize the `COLUMNS` property:

```
abstract class RepositoryBase<T> {
  protected abstract readonly COLUMNS: Record<keyof T, string>;
  strictColumns<
    U extends { [K in keyof T | keyof U]: K extends keyof T ? string : never }
  >(u: U) {
    return u;
  }
}
```

Like this:

```
class UsersRepository extends RepositoryBase<User> {
  protected readonly COLUMNS = this.strictColumns({
    firstName: "first_name",
    lastName: "last_name",
    email: "email"
  });
} // okay

class BadUsersRepository extends RepositoryBase<User> {
  protected readonly COLUMNS = this.strictColumns({
    firstName: "first_name",
    lastName: "last_name",
    email: "email",
    extra: "extra" // error! string is not assignable to never
  });
}
```

This works but the added complexity probably isn't worth the slight reduction in redundancy.  Oh well.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgSgUwA4HswBLCfKATwCE1sAeAFQD4EBvAKAQVynwm3mwATBKEgx4CKNmCD8AO2TkEAYQDyAGQCqAWQByAZQBcWfmUG0A1tnL4AZgnoAaBGKJyA5owDcHLjz4Cwq7wyvjIAK4AtnJgtL6cmgjYAB58coIYLAgA2gDSCG4IVjb29AgAPkXWdgiaALrG+SlpGVUlDggA-C7Qbu4IxnLYAG7YUAgAvr6MABThxpoAlKzxktgQ4VByCOE+nFNTbG58ULZw2LVgYyuctkRQkLrAkdjGrh57CKiPz689UH1PthIsAiMhOm9eh82IcUGgMJorg8cARiKQKElUth0hgUYQSGQqDRaIixsx2JxuLx+HxhFIZPJFCoNDoDAgALwICAACyIYAAdMEIKEItEwDMKZwEHcHhAni9jAAiGWQAD6cl+iscq2+ct+St16s12qlSRBYKVwNByEVvgmix8sO+GGoglJyLw+PRSma2NaeLRhOoVxJSPJvipAVpawZCiUai0en0HK5vIFQpFURiEtWKr1CoQyvuao1Ly1OrQ+b+isNpew5dNVothabNpNUuaMEtqRgioQAHp+0koDwoABCf59AoYOS8EToIjuDUgZAXUgIIajKB2h0wtiLIA)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const userLike = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    az: ''
};

const user: User = userLike;
```

Typescript allow this kind of 'flexible' assignment. He's more strict on the declaration.

There is an interesting proposal about this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936